# Google Fit: Getting the full list of available DataSources for the HistoryClient Android API

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I want to read data using the History API, using the "local" Google Play Fitness API (`com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1`), and I'd like to get the data from all sensors, not just the default sensor.

`DataReadRequest` requires a specific `DataType` object, and the best way I can find to get these is `SensorsClient.findDataSources()` (as documented on https://developers.google.com/fit/android/sensors).
However, this method seems to filter out what it calls "db only sources" which apparently includes everything from my Xiaomi Mi Band 3.

From what I can infer, it boils down to the value of `DataSourcesRequest.includeDbOnlySources` on the "wire" (i.e. Parcelable), but I cannot find an API that would allow me to set it.

Am I missing something?
Is there any solution/workaround?